# Compile Error: Loop must iterate over a collection type: SOBJECT:FeedItem

Tags: trigger, chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed

I am new to Apex and I have the following code to call a function each time a new Chatter post is created:

```
public class MLPost {

    public static void MLPostCreate(FeedItem post) {

        for (FeedItem p : post){
          MLProjectHttpCallout.postContent(p.Body);
        }
    }
     }
```

I am getting this error and don't know what it means:

> Compile Error: Loop must iterate over a collection type:
>   SOBJECT:FeedItem

My trigger to call the above code is as follows:

```
trigger MLPostTrigger on FeedItem (before insert) {

    FeedItem posts = Trigger.new;

    MLPost.MLPostCreate(posts);
}
```

I get the following error when trying to compile the trigger code:

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from LIST to
>   SOBJECT:FeedItem at line 3 column 5

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this particular line with this

```
public class MLPost {

    public static void MLPostCreate(List<FeedItem> posts) {
```

**And update your trigger**

```
trigger MLPostTrigger on FeedItem (before insert) {

  List<FeedItem> posts = Trigger.new;

  MLPost.MLPostCreate(posts);
  //  or you could also use 
  //  MLPost.MLPostCreate(trigger.new);
}
```

**Explanation**
Actually `trigger.new` returns a list of SObjects, so in both the class and trigger code you should work with List. Hence, the error.

Comment: Using plural names for lists and sets helps a bit too i.e. I think its worth keeping the name "posts" in the method signature.